# Does Vow of Peace's calming aura affect the caster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, targeting

Are you affected by your own calming aura? I would think the answer is "no" since you cannot re-enter the area (so maybe you were affected by it initially, but that only lasted until someone took a swing at you).

Comment: I've voted to close this as Too Broad, because you're asking two different questions here.  We have a One Question Per Question policy here, so it would be best if you split this into two questions; one about targeting yourself, and one about the effect ending.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the second question. You can still see it if you look at previous revisions using the [edit history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/98175/revisions) (normally found by clicking the edit time under the post), if you want to copy it to help write a second question post. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Technically yes, but only once upon taking the feat, so basically no.

The effect of the aura is described (BoED p. 48) as:

> ...you are constantly surrounded by a calming aura to a radius of 20 feet. Creatures within the aura must make a successful Will save (DC 10 + one-half your character level + your Cha modifier) or be affected as by the calm emotions spell. Creatures who leave the aura and reenter it receive new saving throws. A creature that makes a successful saving throw and remains in the aura is unaffected until it leaves the aura and reenters. The aura is a mind-affecting, supernatural compulsion.

"Creatures within the aura" doesn't make an exception for the character who took the feat, so they're affected the same as anyone else inside the aura (including the clause about ignoring it if they make their saving throw).

However, the effect of the aura works as the *[calm emotions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/calmEmotions.htm)* spell, which says:

> Any aggressive action against or damage dealt to a calmed creature immediately breaks the spell on all calmed creatures.

So, even if they fail their save, the first time anything takes an aggressive action against the vow-taker, the *calm emotions* effect will end.  Since, as the question points out, there's no way for a creature to leave the effect of its own aura (which would refresh the effect)...it will probably just never be affected again.

In most D&D campaigns, even a character devoted to peace is going to be the target of at least one aggressive action pretty early on.  So, **this isn't likely to be a concern for very long.**

Comment: Or, ya know, the avowed peacekeeper makes the initial saving throw and never has to make it again. A Wisdom-based spellcaster would more-likely-than-not make it, for example.

Comment: @KRyan updated to mention that.